# MIPS Register comparator

Tags: mips, comparator

Given two input registers in MIPS:
$t0, $t1

How would you figure out which one is bigger without using branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SLT/SLTU instruction (Set Less Than [Unsigned]):

```
SLT $t2,$t0,$t1
```

or

```
SLTU $t2,$t0,$t1
```

If $t0 is less than $t1 then $t2 will be 1, otherwise $t2 will be 0.